I have the latest Ubuntu installed on both the SSD and the HD of my desktop. How do I format the HD or erase the Ubuntu files on the HD please?
I have the latest Ubuntu installed on both the SSD and the HD of my desktop. How do I format the HD or erase the Ubuntu files on the HD and partition it  please ?

If you have Ubuntu Desktop, then you have the Disks application.

Last install will be default boot. So make sure the version you are keeping is now the default boot. You can boot into it and just do a sudo grub-install from inside your install you want to keep. Otherwise you need a live installer and full chroot to reinstall grub or Boot-Repair in an Ubuntu live installer.

What is the HD used for? Is it used only for data storage or is it used for something else?

Just create a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution. When you boot from it, during the setup process, you should see an option called "Something else". This allows you to manage your partitions. Does that help? 

Success ! Thank you for your help.

Success ! Thank you for your help.
